# How to solve MemoryError problem?

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow, numpy, error-handling

I have audio signals which I need to convert them to melspectrogram. I am using Deepfilternet to remove background noise. when I use the output of Deepfilternet for next phase like padding, it showed MemoryError that I could solve it using sparse matrices. now when I want to convert those signals to Melspectrogram it shows MemoryError again, while based on the audio signals that I have len(audio_np.toarray().flatten()) = 237401, I should not have MemoryError. I really appreciate it if anyone could help me.  Here is the code for converting audio signals to Melspectrogram:

````
def to_melspectrogram(input_data, var_deep):
    melspect_data = []
    for augmented_sample in input_data:
        audio, filename, label = augmented_sample
        
        if var_deep:
            audio_np = audio.toarray().flatten()
            print(len(audio_np))
        else:
            audio_np = np.asarray(audio)
            
        mel_spec = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=audio_np, sr=sample_rate, fmax=5000)
        mel_spec_db = librosa.power_to_db(mel_spec, ref=np.max)
        
        if mel_spec_db.shape[0] == 1:
            mel_spec_db = mel_spec_db[0]
            
        if var_deep:
            melspect_data_sparse = csr_matrix(mel_spec_db)
            melspect_data.append((melspect_data_sparse, filename, label))
        else:
            melspect_data.append((mel_spec_db, filename, label))
        
        del mel_spec
    
    
    return melspect_data
```
````